# What may be expected after a "colon" notation in a method parameter declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've encountered with a seemingly weird code in a class method in a JavaScript file in a *node.js* project:

```
export const BITS_16 = 16;
export const BITS_32 = 32;
export class MyClass {
   myMethod(valueBits: 16 | 32 = BITS_32): ReturnType {
       //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       //        What does it mean?
   }
}
```

Please elaborate on what exactly does it mean?

---

*<sup>I believe it cannot be a [Bitwise OR Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR), I only expect a "type" identifier after the "colon" notation in that context, and a "default value" that may follow up after an `=` sign!</sup>*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type1 | type2` is a Union type in typescript that means that you can either pass in a `type1` *or* a `type2`. [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

In your case you can pass either `16` or `32`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it :) It totally makes sense that it's not pure JavaScript; but how on earth am I supposed to tell if it's a TypeScript code in a `.js` file?!

Comment: @goodUser actually thats a bad practice, thats what `.ts` is for